# Shell Script: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have read other articles but I can't manage to found the solution to this problem.
I am running the shell script on a Ubuntu terminal.

del2.sh:

echo "Subject Deletion"
echo "Enter 0 to return to Main Menu"
echo -n "Enter subject name to delete it"
read name1

if [  "$name1" ==  "0"  ]
then
echo - n "No changes made"
exit 0

else
        rm $name.txt

fi

Terminal:

[image]

Comment: Your file is saved with DOS newlines.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Just post the text.

Comment: BTW, don't put a space between the `-` and the `n` in `-n`; quote your expansions (`rm "$name.txt"`), and in general, it's safer to use `printf '%s' "some string"` than `echo -n "some string"`; on the last point, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX `echo` spec at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and the excellent answer by Stephane at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: Also, one should always use `IFS= read -r name1` unless you have an explicit reason to *not* do those things; by default, `read` munges input with backslashes, and trims leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am new at this so I don't really know much. What does it mean that my file is saved with DOS newlines?

Comment: DOS/Windows text files separate lines with two characters, a CR and a LF (because this is a separator, not a delimiter, there isn't such a sequence after the very last line). UNIX text files end *all* lines, including the last one, with an LF.

Comment: When a CR is printed, it sends the cursor back to the beginning of the current line. That's why your error messages contain lines that are partially overwritten.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got it thank you so much!